# ng test (angular) hangs in jenkins after successful run

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, karma-jasmine

Our Jenkins test steps just hangs forever even with the correct Karma configurations. Any suggestions or idea would be helpful as I've tried every configuration I can find.

[image]

Our npm test command

```
"test:ci": "ng test --no-watch --no-progress --browsers=ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox",
```

Our karma.config
Notice we have a `singleRun:true` as that seemed to be the important one.

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        // you can add configuration options for Jasmine here
        // the possible options are listed at https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Configuration.html
        // for example, you can disable the random execution with `random: false`
        // or set a specific seed with `seed: 4321`
      },
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    jasmineHtmlReporter: {
      suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/member-web'),
      subdir: '.',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'text-summary' }
      ]
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    // browsers: ['Chrome'],
    browsers: ["ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox"],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: "ChromeHeadless",
        flags: [
          '--headless',
          '--disable-gpu',
          "--no-sandbox",
          "--user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome-test-profile",
          "--disable-web-security",
          "--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0",
          "--remote-debugging-port=9222",
        ],
        debug: true,
      },
    },
    singleRun: true,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. It was something related to the Docker Container we were using. I tried on another image making sure to include chromium and it fixed it. The dockerfile that worked for me is below.

```
FROM node:current-alpine3.12
RUN apk add chromium
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the command line not complain about unknown command of `--no-watch`?

Change the command to:

```
"test:ci": "ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox && echo 'hello'",
```

`--no-progress` does not exist either. Find all flags here: https://angular.io/cli/test.

Comment: It does not, those work. But even if I remove them it doesn't change anything. I've found the karma.config seems to overwrite these values anyway.

Comment: Check out my edit, add an `&& echo 'hello'` after the command to see if the command ended and maybe something is stuck with the Jenkins computer. If you see hello in the terminal, that means the test is done and something is hanging with the computer. If you don't see the `hello`, that means it is stuck on the test. Try removing `restartOnFileChange: true` in `karma.conf.js`. Also, if possible, try creating a blank Angular project and run the test in the CI and see it not hanging and then copy this blank Angular project's config to your config.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I found the solution and posted an answer.